# Pros and Cons of two different ways to recognize palindrome Python

Tags: python

I'm new to python and programming and had a question about the different ways to write a palindrome detector.

From the little that I know, I was able to make one using a while loop...

```
word = str(input("Enter a word: "))
length = len(word)
x = 0
while length-x >= x:
    if word[(length-1)-x] == word[x]:
        y = True
        x += 1
    else:
        y = False
        break           
print (y)
```

But from other palindrome questions I saw the shorter (more pythonic?) way...

```
word = input("Enter a word: ")

rword = word[-1::-1]

print (word == rword)
```

Besides the obvious difference in length, what are the pros and cons of using either code? Also, not sure if this is a dumb question but are either of these considered recursive?

Comment: Neither of them is recursive. Recursion requires a function calling itself, and you haven't defined a function here.

Comment: You could also do something like `all(a == b for a, b in zip(reversed(palindrome), palindrome))`, which does not make a copy and short-circuits.

Comment: There is already much discussion on line, including Stack Overflow postings, on palindrome detection.  What are you still missing for your understanding?

Answer (score 3):

The first has the advantage that it does not require copying the `word`. This will only matter if it becomes big (or you need to do this a few million times).

Note that `word[::-1]` is enough, the beginning is implicitly `0`.

Your first code can also be streamlined a bit (and put into a function):

```
def is_palindrome(s):
    for i in range(len(s)):
        if s[i] != s[-(i + 1)]:
            return False
    return True
```